# How to make dynamic shape adjustment to another shape

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Hi guys i was wondering how to create a shape adjustment with two objects which specifically could be described as the independent cells, one of which is static, and the second one is dynamic and surrounded by "plasma". The movement of the active object must be controllable by the user (WSAD). Collision of the active object with the static one causes the static object to be swallen, though doesn't change it's position stays in place all the time. As the active object moves, passes the swallen object and troughts it out.

See the image below:

[image]

1. Player character
2. When it comes close enough to pink enemy it's starting to swallow it (surround by yellow thing)
3. Pink enemy is completely sourrounded when red circle is in the centre of both.
4. When it leaves enemy it takes off the yellow thing

I was wondering what is the simplest way to do it. I've been thinking about cloth, physics joints, mesh substraction (is it even possible?), some kind of animation... I don't have much time to do it. Can you show me the simplest way. Which tools and approach should i use?  I'm not asking for full code or full solution only for some tips.

Comment: Sounds fairly similar to what Sebastian Lague recently covered on Youtube. The way to get it to work is fairly complicated, but he has some example code you can check out in the description of his [video](https://youtu.be/Cp5WWtMoeKg?t=185).

Answer (score 0):

**Tim Hunter** mentioned a wonderful way, most perfect in 3D.

You can use another approach in 2D :

- Inside `OnCollisionEnter2D` try finding hit points using `Collision2D.contacts` . See [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-contacts.html) reference .
- Create some particle effect there.
- Disable the enemy
- Now play swallowing animation of the player.
- At animation end, enable enemy again.

Maybe calculation is little tricky, still efficient.